# Python codes output not shown in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to python and visual code. I have Python 3 installed, extension of python and code runner also installed in visual code. But every time i run a code in python the output does not show up. I tried all solution available in related threads but nothing seems to work. I am using windows as OS.

I am also wondering if i need to change "python -u" to "python 3".

[image]

Comment: Seems like your python script prints `1000`. Please save the `app.py` script (Ctrl-S) and execute it again.

Comment: You method just worked. Thank you so much for your support. Appreciate it ! @Felix

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not as a picture.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Yes i will do from the future, new in here so learning my ways. Thank you ! Appreciate it !